# Jupyter matplotlib function query

Tags: python, matplotlib

I started a Data Visualisation course today,

We are using the 'matplotlib' library to create a histogram from an imported .csv file,

Here is the code:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

input_file = 'iris.csv'
plt.figure(figsize=(7.5, 4.25))
plt.style.use('classic')

with open(input_file, 'r') as iris_data:
    irises = list(csv.reader(iris_data))

virginica_petal_length = []

num_bins = 10

for petal in range(0, len(irises)-1):
    if irises[petal][4] == 'Iris-virginica':
        virginica_petal_length.append(float(irises[petal][2]))

plt.hist(virginica_petal_length, num_bins, facecolor='red', alpha=0.75)

plt.title('Iris-virginica Petal length', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Petal length (cm)', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('Probability', fontsize=10)

plt.show()
```

Could somebody please explain what is happening here?:

```
with open(input_file, 'r') as iris_data:
    irises = list(csv.reader(iris_data))
```

&

```
for petal in range(0, len(irises)-1):
    if irises[petal][4] == 'Iris-virginica':
        virginica_petal_length.append(float(irises[petal][2]))
```

I really can't get my head around it at the moment!

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(input_file, 'r') as iris_data:
    irises = list(csv.reader(iris_data))
```

You read the content of your file 'iris.csv' with open() in read mode ('r'), and put it in a local variable iris_data.

Then, you use csv.reader() to get all the data present in your file.
And I don't know why, but you store that in a list (of 1 element), called irises.
It could be useful if you had multiple datasets, but in this case, it just makes the code harder to read.

```
for petal in range(0, len(irises)-1):
    if irises[petal][4] == 'Iris-virginica':
        virginica_petal_length.append(float(irises[petal][2]))
```

For each dataframe (having the index petal) of your list irises, irises[petal] refers to the content of the dataframe you're dealing with (more specifically, the object returned by csv.reader, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

With the same notations, irises[petal][4] returns the 5th element of this object, in this case probably the species of irises.

You check that the fifth element is equal to the string 'Iris-virginica'. If yes, you add the second element of your dataset (probably the list of irises petal lengths) to the list of virginica petal lengths. The float function convert the petal length in float type.

If you want to start softly with data visualization, may I suggest to use pandas (a python library) instead of csv to load your data? You could look the pandas.read_csv function.

Good luck with the tutorial!

Comment: Thank you so much! Really good explanation, is the 'r' a keyword or just generic? Yes, I think I need to look at pandas, lambdas (again) and 'NumPy', I have never come across a 'with open' statement before!

Comment: 'r' is an argument, related to the open function (could be 'w' for wrting in the csv, or 'a' to add content). Good choices of libraries! I recommend you to get to know numpy before pandas (because the natural order is to learn arrays before dataframes).